# How to load settings based on file type in Vim?

Tags: vim

Lets say I have two group of settings one for writing and one for programming. How do I modify my `.vimrc` so that the first set load while working on files with the `.md` extension and the latter with `html/js/css` ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use autocommands. For example, here are the settings from my `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.js,*.html
      \ setlocal indentkeys=!^F,o
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.md
      \ setlocal filetype=markdown | syntax clear
```

`setlocal` is used instead of `set` so that only the buffer matching the filename pattern is affected. Otherwise, the change to an option like `shiftwidth` will affect *all* buffers every time you load a `*.foo` file.

The `\` is the [line-continuation character](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#line-continuation), which lets you split a single command over multiple lines to increase readability.

The `|` character is the [bar](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%3abar) which is used to chain together multiple commands in one line.

See [autocmd.txt in the vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html) for more.

Comment: @andewdotn Thanks a lot! One question: do the settings need to be set as `setlocal`? can they just be set as `set`? Sorry I'm not very familiar with vimscript. Is it necessary to wrap those settings inside conditional blocks or something?

Comment: I usually see settings as this: `set expandtab` with `set`.

Comment: If you don’t use `setlocal` then the setting will apply to all buffers which will be really annoying if you have multiple files open. See `:he :setlocal`. You don’t need to wrap that in a block or anything; the corresponding settings will be applied only if the filename matches the pattern.

Comment: Thanks. What I mean right now in your example I don't see how the `setlocal` is "connected" with `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile`. It seems like the `setlocals` are "nested" inside? Could you expand the example to include one ore more settings?

Comment: Oh, I see—the ``\`` at the beginning of the line is a [line-continuation character](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#line-continuation). Technically that’s the same as writing `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.js,*.html setlocal indentkeys=!^F,o` all on one line, it’s just more readable and more customary to do it with the ``\`` at the start of the next line. Note that vimscript syntax is actually defined in [`eval.html`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html).

Comment: @andrewdotn could you include this explanation of backslash in your answer for future visitors?

Answer (score 7):

Though `:autocmd`s based on `FileType` are a quick and easy way for your `~/.vimrc` (as suggested by @andrewdotn), Vim has a proper abstraction for that: *filetype plugins*.

Put settings and buffer-local mappings into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`.)